# AWS CDK: fixed logical ids

Tags: identifier, aws-cdk

Currently logical ID of a resource is formed by concatenating the names of all of the constructs in the resource’s path and appending an eight-character MD5 hash.

This produces garbage like `VpcPrivateSubnet1DefaultRouteBE02A9ED` and unfortunatelly makes it unable to query the resources by their logical id.

Is there any way to control how logical ids are named?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In TypeScript the method you are looking for is `overrideLogicalId`. But you have to get the lower level CfnVpc construct first by using the following code (TypeScript again):

```
 let vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'vpc', { natGateways: 1 })
 let cfnVpc = vpc.node.defaultChild as ec2.CfnVPC
 cfnVpc.overrideLogicalId('MainVpc')
```

Results in the following yaml:

```
  MainVpc:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit late to the party but here is my implementation. I removed the random characters at the end of the string and replaced it with the logical ID which are unique throughout the project.

```
protected allocateLogicalId(cfnElement: CfnElement): string {
  return cfnElement.logicalId.split('.')[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution in `Python`:

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_lambda as lambda_

api_function = lambda_.Function(
    self,
    "lambda_func",
    code=lambda_.Code.from_bucket(bucket=s3_bucket, key='lambda.zip'),
    runtime=typing.cast(lambda_.Runtime, lambda_.Runtime.PYTHON_3_9), # Bug in CDK/PyLance; use cast to mitigate for now
    timeout=Duration.seconds(900),
    handler="rest_client.handler"
    )

cfn_func = api_function.node.default_child
cfn_func.override_logical_id("NewLogicalId")
```

(Note: `PyLance` throws the following error, but `cdk ls` and `cdk synth` work as expected:

```
override_logical_id: Unknown
Cannot access member "override_logical_id" for type "IConstruct"
  Member "override_logical_id" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
"override_logical_id" is not a known member of "None"
```

Please note: It is generally not recommended to change logical IDs as changing the logical ID of a resource causes the resource to be replaced. The old resource will get deleted, and a new resource with the new logical ID gets created.

From the docs:

> Avoid changing the logical ID of a resource after it has been created. Since AWS CloudFormation identifies resources by their logical ID, if you change the logical ID of a resource, AWS CloudFormation deletes the existing resource, and then creates a new resource with the new logical ID, which may cause service interruption or data loss.