# How to get the resource logical id of cloudformation template to cdk - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am migrating the cloudformation template to CDK. The only problem is I don't know how to get the same logical ID of parent stack from the cloudformation template to CDK. Any help please! Thank you! or is there a way to override cdk generated logical id? This will be really helpful when migrating templates to CDK w/o Cfn actually deleting and recreating the resource due to change in logical id.

```
        from aws_cdk.core import Stack, Construct, StackProps
        import aws_cdk.aws_cloudformation as cfn
        import aws_cdk.aws_s3 as s3
        import aws_cdk.core as core
        import aws_cdk.cloudformation_include as cfn_inc
        
        
        
        class MyNestedStack1(cfn.NestedStack):
            def __init__(self, scope, id, *, parameters=None, timeout=None, notifications=None):
                super().__init__(scope, id)
                
                bucket = s3.Bucket.from_bucket_name(self, "S3Bucket", 
                   bucket_name = "sample-bucket-sample-tin-test")
                bucket_arn = core.Fn.get_att("S3Bucket", "Arn")
    
        
        class MyParentStack1 (Stack):
            def __init__(self, scope, id, *, description=None, env=None, stack_name=None, tags=None, synthesizer=None, terminationProtection=None):
                super().__init__(scope, id, stack_name='aws-stack-nightly')
    

                MyNestedStack(self, "AWSHealthStack")
```

As you can see on the screenshot. The  **AWSHealthStack** is the logical ID of the cf template. Then when I deployed that to cdk it creates another logical id (**AWSHealthStackNestedStackAWSHealthStackNestedStackResource7F23391A**)

[image]

Well in here I tried this code so I can override the logical id using CFnInclude. But I got this error:

> jsii.errors.JSIIError: Missing required properties for
> @aws-cdk/cloudformation-include.CfnIncludeProps: templateFile

```
class MyParentStack(core.Stack):
    def __init__(self, scope, id, *, description=None, env=None, stack_name=None, tags=None, synthesizer=None, terminationProtection=None):
        super().__init__(scope, id, stack_name='aws-stack-nightly')

        stack = MyNestedStack(self, "AWSHealthStack1")
        cfn_template = cfn_inc.CfnIncludeProps(template_file="monitoring-template/aws-stack.yml",
            nested_stacks=[stack])
        cfn_template1 = cfn_inc.CfnInclude(self, "AWSHealthStack2", template_file="monitoring-template/aws-stack.yml",
            nested_stacks=cfn_template)
        cfn_stack = core.Fn.get_att("AWSHealthStack", "Arn")
        cfn_template1.override_logical_id("AWSHealthStack")
```

Comment: [typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213637/aws-cdk-fixed-logical-ids) has overrideLogicalId('abc')

Comment: Yes but I prefer using the python. In python which is this one `override_logical_id("AWSHealthStack")`. Is there a way that I can used that on **class MyParentStack1 (Stack)**?

Comment: Have you done through POC on CDK? Every resource I used had some defects, even breaking change of CLI prerequisite). Please make sure the resource you intended to use works. Every 2, 3 weeks a new release coming out asking to update.

Comment: Currently approx 1300 issues open in https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by renaming the logical id.

```
stack.rename_logical_id("AWSHealthNestedStackAWSHealthNestedStackResource7F23391A", "AWSHealthStack")
```

But if there is anything that has a better approach would be much appreciated.